WSO2 Identity Server 7.0.0 : Management Console is currently operating in legacy mode
I downloaded the product WSO2 Identity Server v7.0.0.
I would like to configure a WSO2 IS cluster using Carbon consoles,
but apparently the CARBON console that I have locally offers limited functionality that i can't configure a cluster. (as shown in the picture below)
I have the message displayed on the console CARBON :
"Management Console is currently operating in legacy mode. It offers limited functionality, including Multi-Tenancy, XACML, and Keystore Management. For a more comprehensive suite of features, we strongly recommend using the new console."
https://localhost:9443/carbon/admin
I use the browser Microsoft Edge for Business Version 124.0.xxxx.xx (64 bits).
Does anyone know how to switch to the new CARBON console ?
Thanks a lot !
enter image description here
enter image description here
for example: I tried to configure the carbon_home.

The legacy Carbon Management Console accessible via https://localhost:9443/carbon/admin has limited functionality as the full set of capabilities is instead available in the new Carbon Console, which is accessible via https://localhost:9443/console.
Please note that there have been changes to the names of some functionalities with this upgrade. For example, service providers are now called "applications", while identity providers are called "connections".
Here are some documentation links on applications and connections:

Setting up a sample application (i.e., service provider)
Setting up a connection (i.e., identity provider)

A comprehensive list of what's new in this release can be found in the second link shared in this answer.
If there is any other page which you are unable to find in the new Carbon Console, please do let us know and we would be happy to help.

As others have said, the CARBON console now offers limited functionality. All features removed from the CARBON console now can be accessed via the new Identity Server Console at https://localhost:9443/console.
If you want to configure a IS cluster, please follow the latest IS deployment guide at https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/deploy/deployment-guide/.
